# I need a solution of a programme(link given) by using c language

Tags: c

http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1010
please give a solution of this code, using c language.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int t,l,s,c,j,i,k,d,e[41000];
    scanf("%u",&t);
    d=0;
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%u %u",&s,&c);
        if(c%2!=0)
        {
            for(l=1;l<=s;l++)
            {
                if(l%2==0) d=(c/2)+d;
        else d=((c/2)+1)+ d;
            }
            }
        else if(c%2==0)
        {
            for(k=1;k<=s;k++)
            {
            d=d+(c/2);
            }
        }
        e[i]=d;
    }
    for(j=0;j<t;j++)
    {
        printf("Case %u: %u\n",j+1,e[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I did this. This gives correct result for one case only. when it goes to the 2nd test the value of d is adding with the previous value of d. that is making my code wrong. please answer me why this is happening? if you have a better solution using C, please give me it.

Comment: If the problem is that the value of `d` accumulates from test to test, then the natural solution seems to be to reset that variable's value to 0 at the beginning of each test.  Without having read the external problem statement, my guess would be that that would mean moving `d=0;` inside the `for` loop.